# CSS: absolutely position div above parent div

Tags: css

I want to position a DIV absolutely, at top: 0.  The yellow div (#menu) in [this diagram](http://i112.photobucket.com/albums/n180/SRD001/screenshots/g7ZFx.png) is the one in question.

I have HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container_head">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div id="container_body">
            <div id="main">
                <div id="menu">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
                <div id="content">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="container_foot">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and CSS:

```
#container_head {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #00F;
    z-index: 10;
}
#container_body {
    width: 100%;
}
#container_foot {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #F00;
}
#main {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
#menu {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,0,0.5);
    width: 170px;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}
#content {
    background-color: #0F0  ;
    width: 750px;
    padding: 10px;
    float: right;
}
.clear {clear: both;}
```

However, the yellow div does not appear at y position 0.  [Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SRD75/2fYGj/).

***Update***

I appreciate the answers.  I am still in a quandary.  `#container_head` is not going to be the same height for every user.  It is a responsive slider.  Also, I need `#menu` to be on the left side of a region the same shape as `#main`, so it slots in next to `#content`.

Comment: you can take the position relative off of #main

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you cannot modify the HTML, only CSS?

Comment: This thread is nuts.  And, the initial code is poor: 1) width of 100% set for blocks, 2) z-index is set on non-positioned elements, 3) floats are cleared using markup, 4) the naming conventions are awkward (why not use header tag or call a div a #header), and 5) HTML structure stinks.  Regarding the latter, if position of the #menu is affected by the #container_header, then it should be within it.  Here's a good one: the #main is positioned relatively.  Why?  The only absolute block within it is #menu and it needs to be tied to the #container_header or the body.  Thumbs down!

Comment: @DRD I agree.  It looks like the OP tried a bunch of different things, and didn't remove them when they didn't work.  I'd love to see this code over on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, where we could ask what the original intention was and try to start over.  For this question, I didn't feel it would help the OP to do a massive code rewrite (although some of the answers have done so), so I simply worked with his fiddle and did minimal changes.  At least I removed one of the css lines that was causing trouble, and I tried to make it work if container_head changed margins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having read this thread, your comments and the updated question, it seems that you are not inclined to change your markup and layout. With this in mind let's fix only the styles to suit your existing markup.

Before you go on, have a look at this demo:

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/2fYGj/6/***

There are a few problems that we need to understand and we'll fix them one by one.

***(1.)*** You have percent widths on containers and pixel widths on children. In your question you state that the containers esp. header needs be responsive. I would suggest using same units for the entire layout i.e. using percent widths for all your layout components.

***(2.)*** You have paddings and margins applied to some elements which will cause problems on widths if you don't have proper `box-sizing` model to start with.

Let's fix these two problems:

We add a minimal reset to your CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

We now apply percent widths to all elements:

```
#main {
    width: 100%;
    ...
}
#menu {
    width: 10%; /* within 100% of parent i.e. main */
    ...
}
#content {
    width: 70%; /* within 100% of parent i.e. main */
    ...
}
```

Now on to other problems:

***(3.)*** You have percent widths on your `container_head`, `container_body` and `container_foot`. 100% width of what? It is of the parent. So we have to apply width to the `html,body` as well, to be on safe side.

We fix that by adding this to your CSS:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
}
```

***(4.)*** You have your `#menu` absolutely positioned. Now, absolute position means taking the element out of flow and making it positioned relatively to its nearest relatively positioned parent. If no such parent exists, then it becomes relative to body. In your case, its immediate parent i.e. `#main` is relatively positioned, so the menu tried to position itself relative to `#main`. But, that's **not** what you want. You want it to be relative to `#container_head`. But `#container_head` is not in its parent hierarchy. (And you don't want to change your markup) otherwise adding a wrapper would have solved this problem.

So we fix this by removing `position: relative` on `#main`:

```
#main {
    ...
    /* position: relative;  <-- Remove positioning from main */
}
```

This will force the `#menu` to be positioned relative to page. This will introduce another problem, which is that if you have a `margin-top` applied to `#container_head`, then the menu will pull up. To mitigate that, you will then have to apply a `top` on `#menu` which is equal to the `margin-top` of `#container_head`. (This can be best understood by this demo: ***http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/LbRKb/***)

***(5.)*** You need your `#menu` to line-up with the `#content`. And `#menu` is absolutely positioned. Absolute position means it is out of its flow and hence your `float`s on menu and content are now meaningless.

We fix it by assigning a percent margin to both menu and content:

```
#menu {
    width: 10%; 
    top: 0; left: 10%; /* whatever indent you want from left */
    /* float: left <-- not required now */
    ...
}
#content {
    width: 70%;
    margin-right: 10% /* right margin equal to left pos of menu */
    margin-left: 20%; /* left margin equal to left pos of menu + menu width */
    /* float: right <-- not required now */
    ...
}
```

***(6.)*** Because your menu is absolutely positioned now, its height may exceed that of `#main` if there is little or no content in `#content`. In that scenario it will overlap main into the footer and even beyond.

We fix this by assigning a min-height to both `#menu` and `#main` and making sure that main's height is more than that of menu:

```
#main {
    min-height: 200px; /* must be more than that of menu */
    ...
}
#menu {
    min-height: 100px;
    ...
}
```

.

There you go. Now you have a layout that exactly resembles the diagram picture you posted.

### Updated (based on Op's comments):

In order to constrain the menu and content size using `max-width`, the above method will break the gap between menu and content as mentioned by the Op in the comments below.

To fix this turned out to be easy. The trick would be to use `right` instead of `left` on the `#menu`.

***Demo 3: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/2fYGj/17/
Demo 3 (Full-Screen): http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/2fYGj/17/embedded/result/***

Hope that helps.

.

Comment: Brilliant abhitalks.  You nailed it.

Comment: I wanted to keep all of the content to below a maximum width.  So, I gave `#menu {max-width: 229px;}` and `#content {max-width: 850px;}`.  You might imagine this broke the layout on large screens.  See [here](http://i112.photobucket.com/albums/n180/SRD001/screenshots/bampt.png).  How do I keep the layout tight?

Comment: Yes. This design is not responsive as you would have to calculate the left margin of content depending on menu width and position. The only way out would be not enforce max-widths.

Comment: Is there another way we can build the layout but ensure there are max-widths?

Comment: @SR7: On second thoughts, I tried it. The trick would be to use `right` instead of `left` on the `#menu`. [(See this Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/2fYGj/17/), and [(See it Full-Screen)](http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/2fYGj/17/embedded/result/). Added to the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Your `#menu` is inside `#main`. And `#main` is `position: relative;` meaning it is "positioned". Absolute positioned elements are positioned relative to their closest positioned parent. Therefore, your `top: 0;` on `#menu` is zero from the top of `#main`, not the top of the document.

You can fix this in a few ways:

1. Move `#menu` out of `#main`
2. Don't position `#main` relative (this will influence any absolute positioned elements inside `#main` so be careful)
3. Give `#container_head` a fixed height and then give `#menu` a top of, e.g., `-30px`
4. Make `#menu` `position: fixed;` (this will make it relative to the *viewport* rather than the document, so it will no longer scroll with the document. That may or may not be desirable. Also, `position: fixed` doesn't work in IE 6 or IE 7 in compatibility mode.)

Comment: Thank you very much @gwcoffey.  I have added an update to the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 1):

I took your fiddle and modified it in two ways.  First, I put #menu inside #container_head, second, I removed the top: 0; from the #menu css.  See http://jsfiddle.net/J9E47/

```
<body>

    <div id="container_head">
        <div id="menu">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div id="container_body">
        <div id="main">

            <div id="content">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="container_foot">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</body>
```

and

```
#container_head {
width: 100%;
background-color: #00F;
z-index: 10;
}
#container_body {
width: 100%;
}
#container_foot {
width: 100%;
background-color: #F00;
}
#main {
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}
#menu {
background-color: rgba(255,255,0,0.5);
width: 170px;
padding: 10px;
float: left;
position: absolute;
z-index: 100;
}
#content {
background-color: #0F0  ;
width: 750px;
padding: 10px;
float: right;
}
.clear {clear: both;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very quick fiddle `[http://jsfiddle.net/tL55Y/][1]` . You need to reorient your structure and See If This could help you. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much Vaibhav.  I have added an update to the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 0):

As gwcoffey explained, absolute positioned elements are positioned according to their immediate parent element. You won't get the behavior you are looking for with the structure as you have it now.

Here is a sample if an alternative structure:

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/yeluku/1/)

Let me explain changes:

1. Add a container that covers your three sections container_head, container_body, and container_foot. Make sure this gets `position: relative;`

   ```
   <div class="container"></div>
   ```

   *Note, you wouldn't need to make a container around them, but if you didn't you would have to make a couple very small changes to account for the default `body` margins. You'd still need the structure in the following point, just without the outer `div`.*
2. Make it so your menu is in the level immediately below this relatively positioned element and that it is in the same level as the `#container_head`, by simplifying your `#container_body` into just `#menu` and `#content`

   ```
   <div class="container">
     <div id="container_head"></div>
     <div id="menu"></div>
     <div id="content"></div>
     <div id="container_foot"></div>
   </div>
   ```

Now, with this structure you can be a bit more flexible and write simpler markup. Since the positioning will take the menu out of the flow of the page, you'll need to offset the position of the content by applying a margin of at least the menu left right margin + left right padding + width.

Answer (score 0):

in my example I have changed all of your IDs to classes as it is much easier to override classes than IDs as a general rule. Your structure is the same though, apart from the wrapper I added. Please see my Pen: http://codepen.io/mofeenster/pen/jLJhw

It was simply a matter of changing where you used position relative. To get the menu to go to the top with Absolute positioning you needed to make use of the wrapping div I added. you can manipulate elements into moving all over the place depending upon which divs are relative and absolute.

Another example of this is another pen I created for a similar purpose see it here: http://codepen.io/mofeenster/pen/nErks

I think that this answers everything you have asked.

Answer (score 0):

**First of all,** when you set an element's positioning as absolute, it won't be considered a part of the general layout, and it'll be ignored when positioning the other divs. So if you want to align #content and #menu, you'll need to manually set a margin equal to #menu's width + paddings in #content:

```
#content {
    background-color: #0F0  ;
    width: 750px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 190px; /* Allow space for #menu considering its padding */
    /* Floating is not necessary for this. */
}
```

**Second,** *position: absolute* will position the div relative to its closest parent with *position: relative* set. So in your case, #menu will be positioned relative to #main. What you must do is remove *position: relative* from #main so that #menu gets positioned relative to its next closest parent which is *body*.

```
#main {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**And last,** when using absolute positioning, floating makes no sense so you can remove it from #menu.

```
#menu {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,0,0.5);
    width: 170px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

**Here's the full CSS:**

```
#container_head {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #00F;
    z-index: 10;
}
#container_body {
    width: 100%;
}
#container_foot {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #F00;
}
#main {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#menu {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,0,0.5);
    width: 170px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}
#content {
    background-color: #0F0;
    width: 730px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 190px;
}
.clear {clear: both;}
```

[Here's the JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLj2m/3/)

Comment: *position: relative* is the most confusing property in CSS. Your question is mostly related to its proper use.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code and this may be an answer for your question:

http://jsfiddle.net/2fYGj/7/

I have wrapped up `div.container_head` and `div.container_body` inside another `div`:

```
<body>
<div>
  <div id="container_head"><!-- Contents --></div>
  <div id="container_body"><!-- Contents --></div>
</div>

<div id="container_foot">
</div>
</body>
```

For the CSS part, I have removed(commented) position of `#main`:

```
#main {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*position: relative;*/
}
```

And some style for newly added div:

```
body > div {
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the element `#main` remove `position:relative;`

Answer (score 0):

An element with `position: absolute` is always positioned relatively to the nearest containing element having `position: absolute` or `position: relative` set. This is the reason, why your `#menu` div is pinned to the top of you `#main` div and as many previous posters suggested, simply **removing `position: relative` from `#main` lets break `#menu` out to the top**. Additionally to pin it at the top of your `#container_head` add

```
body {
  position: relative;
}
```

This does not affect the width calculation, so your `menu` resides left of `content`.